# Should 'everything' be spring managed in a Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We are working on a new application and we want to use Spring (college project!)

When you are writing a new Spring application, should each and every object be Spring injected?

```
class A {
    ...
    AHelper helper = new AHelper();
    helper.doSomething();
    ...
}

class AHelper {
    public void doSomething(){}
}
```

1. In this case, should AHelper be Spring injected into A using a setter? If class A depends on 5 helpers, should all of them be injected? Is that the best practice and if yes what are we getting out of it?
2. Also, if class AHelper depends on AHelperHelper and that in turn depends on AHelperHelperHelper, should this entire dependency chain be configured in the XML. It just feels wrong to me!

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion it is preferable to decide at the beginning of a project which kind of objects would be beans and which wouldn't. It can be based on their *responsability* or, as in my case, the *layer* where they are placed. This rule is very easy to explain to other team members and it minimizes modifications in the middle of the project and *surprises*.

So, what I usually do:

- **Controller**, **service** and **repository** layers are Spring beans. All of them are usually wired together, and it's an overcomplication to have some beans and some regular objects (POJOs) at the same time.
- **Model** entities are not Spring beans. Developement is usually simpler if model entities are just POJOs. Also, if you load hundreds of them in a single operation, and they are all beans, it can lead to poor performance.
- **DTO**, **VO**... well, I usually don't need them, but if I do, I treat them as model entities.
- **Utility** classes. There are three kinds of them:

  - Static method classes: obviously they must not be beans. It won't help you.
  - *Simple* objects, for example your own kind of map: just leave them as regular objects.
  - ***Helpers***, such as an CsvFileConstructor: In my opinion these are just services, but some people prefer to put them in *util* package. Anyway, they usually need some configuration (in a CSV case: encoding, base path, separator...), so you can get some benefits if you make them beans.
- **Exceptions**, **enums**, ...: of course, no beans.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen projects in which every object is injected, and it's a nightmare.

I would identify the *larger-scale* components that you're likely to build and create them as Spring beans if:

1. you're likely to want to configure them
2. use Spring AoP on them (e.g. for transactions etc.)
3. clients are likely to want to recompose your application using these components

For instance, in my current project, we Spring-enable new larger scale components that we may want to enable/disable for release, or that other teams will consume, or that we need to enable JMX (via Spring AoP) for.

Comment: What is we want to do some fancy AOP logging thing? Every thing should be Spring injected? Do you suggest not doing AOP logging (or any AOP that potentially touches every class) in the interest of avoiding the 'nightmare' you mentioned?

Comment: How about testing? If based on your suggestions, I decide to make A & AHelper not beans (and just do a 'new AHelper();' in A) and also lets assume AHelper talks to some real service, how can I test A now without touching that service?

Comment: I know this is 7 years later. But this issue has been addressed by the newer mocking frameworks. Unless there's a real need to swap out implementations at runtime in production I prefer simple Java objects.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything. But in that case, it would probably be a good idea, yes. What you gain is the possibility to unit-test `A` by injecting a mock `AHelper` in it. You could gain many other things (security, transactional aspects, etc.), but it depends on the context and on which kind of objects `A` and `AHelper` are.

The same applies to all your chain. Note though that XML is not the preferred way of configuring a Spring application. Annotations are easier to use, and allow having a minimal XML config file.